# How to use TFramedScrollBox correctly with Touchscrolling, if there are Buttons inside?

Tags: delphi, windows-8, firemonkey, smooth-scrolling, delphi-xe7

I have derived a `TFramedScrollBox` to implement in my component a class which constructs me on a given dimension (x and y) buttons onto the FramedScrollBox. This works fine. Touchscrolling on this object works fine, if the property `Touch.Pan` is set to `true`. Then i even can scroll over the buttons and by "touching" or "tapping" the buttons the click event happens right after the touch. This derived component, my component, is used all over the application, because it need to be.

#### The Problem(s)

The given app is running in fullscreen mode on win 8 systems which is currently necessary for our business. In the above explained situation is not possible to tap the buttons fast after the others, because some click events don't rises. And the logic behind is not necessary. That is one problem... If I switch the form to none fullscreenmode then a touch on different buttons rises the click event immediatly as wished. Now i have discovered that if the above mentioned property Pan  is set to false, then even on fullsceenmode every touch click rises the event but now the scrollbox don't scrolls by touch gesture...

Now comes my question in the title...

Ps. if wished i can send a simple sample...